# How can I post ajax data to aspx.cs page load event asp.net?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I'm working with the ajax and asp.net and I want to send my data with url to aspx.cs page load event.

How can I do this?

What I have tried is:

```
 the ajax code
         <script type="text/javascript"> 
           $(document).ready(function () {

         $(document).on("click", ".get_tsk", function (){

           
            var timeidtask = $(this).data('id');
          alert(timeidtask);

            $.ajax({
                url: 'MaxTime.aspx.cs',
                data: { id: timeidtask },
                dataType: "json",
                method: 'post',
                success: function (data) {
                    //  alert(data[0].Status);
                   

                },
                error: function (err) {

                }
            });

        });
    });

</script>
```

the aspx.cs page code is

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
     
   string view=id;
    }
```

I want to display id which I send from ajax in page load event.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the `[WebMethod]` attribute, like this:

```
[WebMethod]
public static object YourMethodName(int id)
{
    //do something
}
```

In case you have a **GET** request, then you need to add an additional attribute:

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true)]
public static object YourMethodName(int id)
{
    //do something
}
```

By the way, in your `url` attribute, change this:

```
url: 'MaxTime.aspx.cs',
```

with this:

```
url: "MaxTime.aspx/YourMethodName",
```

Comment: i want to get  (string id) in page load ? how can i do that

Comment: @fazal: I'm a little confused here. If you're using **Ajax** in an **ASP.Net** application is because you're supposed to work asynchronously, in order to avoid doing postbacks. Could you explain me what do you want to do in your `page_load` event, please?

Comment: I want to get the id which i pass through ajax post method in my page load even so that i can search data

Comment: @fazal: If you execute your Ajax request in the `$(document).ready()`, it will execute as soon as your page is fully loaded. Then you can call your own method, server-side (like in my example), an perform your searching operation there.

Comment: I will use C# for searching process . For now i need a id to display in page load event.How can i do that?

Comment: @fazal: I think you're confused. When i said **your own method server-side**, I meant a C# method. Anyway, in your aspx page you can add a hidden value `<input type="hidden" id="hfValue" value="YourValue" runat="server" />`, in the `$(document).ready()` section include this `$("form").submit();`, and in your aspx.cs `protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) { if (IsPostBack) { int value = Convert.ToInt32(hfValue.Value); } }`

Now, let me ask you, what's the point of using **Ajax** if you want to work **synchronously**?

Comment: $(document).on("click", ".get_tsk", function (){

               
                var timeidtask = $(this).data('id');
            //    alert(timeidtask);
                localStorage.setItem("Value", timeidtask);
                location.replace("https://localhost:44320/App/Screenshot.aspx")

                return false  }); i use this method to post to another page